# Using map() in a split-apply-combine to run multiple regressions with regression weights

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

Say I have some data that looks like this:

```
N <- 200
X <- sample(letters[1:5],N, replace = T)
Y <- rnorm(N)
W <- abs(rnorm(N))

my_data <- tibble(X, Y, W)
```

I want to run an intercept-only regression on each subset of my data defined by `X`. To do so, I use `nest()`, `mutate()` and `map()` like so:

```
my_data %>%
  group_by(X) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(fit = map(data, ~lm(Y ~ 1, data = .x)))
```

While this code works, when I try to incorporate regression weights, like this:

```
my_data %>%
  group_by(X) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(fit = map(data, ~lm(Y ~ 1, data = .x, weights = W)))
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `fit`.
x missing or negative weights not allowed
ℹ Input `fit` is `map(data, ~lm(Y ~ 1, data = .x, weights = W))`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: X = "a".
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Where am I going wrong?

(Disclaimer: I am new to the tidyverse so am likely doing something dumb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write it this way:

```
my_data %>%
 group_by(X) %>%
 nest() %>%
 mutate(fit = map(data, ~lm(Y ~ 1, data = .x, weights = .x$W)))
```

The point is that at that point W is not an existing column anymore.
It exists only inside `data`. With `map` you are looping over `data` which at that point is a list of dataframes.

Therefore to call W, you need to call it through `$`

Also, define W as:

```
W <- abs(rnorm(N))
```

Because you can't have negative weights.

---

Alternatively, you can do it as follow:

```
my_data %>%
 group_by(X) %>%
 summarise(fit = list(lm(Y ~ 1, weights = W)))
```

It will give you the same result. [almost: because X will be sorted]

Check this out:

```
fit1 <- my_data %>%
 arrange(X) %>% 
 group_by(X) %>%
 nest() %>%
 mutate(fit = map(data, ~lm(Y ~ 1, data = .x, weights = .x$W))) %>% 
 pull(fit)

fit2 <- my_data %>%
 group_by(X) %>%
 summarise(fit = list(lm(Y ~ 1, weights = W))) %>% 
 pull(fit)

identical(map(fit1, coef), map(fit2, coef))
#> TRUE
```

---

If you just need the coefficients, you can do it this way:

```
my_data %>%
 group_by(X) %>%
 summarise(fit = coef(lm(Y ~ 1, weights = W)))
```

Comment: Many thanks! And have fixed the weights typo.

Comment: I made an edit to provide another solution. Check it out

Comment: As an alternative, there's the (experimental) `dplyr::group_map()` function.

Comment: Sounds good! I suppose that, since it was required to have a dataframe at the end, `dplyr::group_modify` could be more appropriate.